# Listing Groups in a mail template

Tags: groups, tokens, templates

I'm creating an email template to be used to confirm a contact's membership status, and I would like to include a list of the Groups (representing Committees in our case) that the contact belongs to.

I have tried including the token {contact.Group(s)} (with various capitalizations, inclusion of parentheses, etc.) without success.

I can include a token that sends the user to the form where they can see and edit those memberships, but I would rather just list them.  I thought this would just be in the drop-down list of tokens, but no, and I can't find any reference to this in the manuals.  Any suggestions?

Thanks as always.  I'm using CiviCRM for WordPress, current versions.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, that token doesn't exist, in core or in an extension.  It's not a bad idea though; it would be quick to write.  As with most tokens that list multiple fields, the real trick is in formatting.  Some will want them in a particular order; some want them comma-separated vs. each on their own line, etc.

Answer (score 4):

As said by Jon its not available in core or in an extension. You can either write  extension and implement hook_civicrm_tokens  and hook_civicrm_tokenValues to add and generate token for the contact or you can use smarty with the help of Civi api

eg:

```
{capture assign=contactId}{contact.contact_id}{/capture}
{crmAPI var='result' entity='GroupContact' action='get' sequential=0 contact_id=$contactId status="Added"}

{foreach from=$result.values item=groupcontact}
  {$groupcontact.title}</br>
{/foreach}
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: I admit I do not have any idea how to implement what you suggest.  I think I will need to pay a developer to write the extensions and explain to me how to implement them.

Comment: While at it, we have other things we might like to include in an email template, re the contact's Membership (the most recent, presumably, if there are someday more than one membership per person) :  Either the "Member since" date -- or ideally that date plus ninety days.  
Anyone want to offer to help me with that?  And what should I expect to pay?  Is this an appropriate place to recruit for that?  
Thanks!

Comment: Both Jon and Pradeep could do a good job, and I think Jon is an independent contractor these days. You might want to consider https://civicrm.org/extensions/civitoken and have the groups token be added to that extension. You might also be interested in https://civicrm.org/extensions/related-membership-tokens though it's not exactly what you want. Rates and hours vary. Maybe indicate your email as name (at) domain (dot) com or whatever and then ask people to contact you.

Comment: @JoeMurray I can't see the CiviToken extension. Did you mean https://civicrm.org/extensions/fuzion-tokens?

Comment: Yes, Fuzion tokens are also known as Civi tokens extension